# Using WebParts, how can I let anonymous users see customizations made by authorized users?

Tags: c#, .net, web-parts

I have an app that allows a user (fred) to login and customize a page.  I then want anonymous users to access the page using the login users name (fre) and see the customized page.

Is there a way that I can programmatically load the profile?

The anonymous users do not have the password for the page, just the user name.  I have the web.config set to allow access for everyone to the page, but the WebParts do not get loaded because they are part of the user's profile. I was hoping I could take the users name and programmatically load the respective WebParts for that user.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to have individuall pages for each user, or do you want to allow fred to do customization for every person who is visiting the page?

Comment: Individual Pages for each user.  I thought maybe I could load the WebPartPersonalization for the user, since the visitior will be entering the user name.

Answer (score 0):

you could load it based on session state where session["username"] = fred for example

Comment: tbh i am a little hazy with web parts but i think you can create profiles in the web.config and call them from the code. Best to look up asp.net profiles in books or on line, i think this link is something similar: http://www.theserverside.net/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=38241